# jQuery is ready from dynamically loaded control

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have created an asp.net applicaton that contains a aspx that has an update panel.
I have a button inside the update panel that loads usercontrols.

My usercontrol I am trying to use the jquery facebox plugin.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

     $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage: '/styles/images/facebox/loading.gif',
        closeImage: '/styles/images/facebox/closelabel.png'
    });
});
```

so for any anchor tag I want this plugin to work on I just need to add `rel="facebox"` and it works nicely.
I have tried adding rel="facebox" to a tag I am wanting to use in my usercontrol however nothing happens apart from the anchor tag redircting me to the link reference in the href

I have tried adding the above documet.ready code to both the aspx & ascx however nothing happens.

Is this due to the dynamic loading of the usercontrol? is this some other steps I need to do to?

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: I think you might need to show us some more of your code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be because of the update panel. Code added dynamically to a page is not automatically matched by a jQuery selector, so event handlers will not fire. To get around this, you could either reregister the event handlers after loading the new code, or you can use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Since these handlers are registered within facebox, you may need to modify facebox's code. Here is one instance that would need changed: [line 159](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox/blob/master/src/facebox.js#L159)

Answer (score 0):

Time to start troubleshooting. Add this line: console.log("testing1") at different places, and make sure those log messages show up in the Firebug console in Firefox.

- If they don't, you have some problem
  that's not covered by the info in
  your question.
- If the ready function
  triggers, but facebox does not, it's
  a problem with facebox.

Which was it?

Comment: I added that to my masterpage,aspx page and the usercontrol. I see that everything apart from the usercontrol is writing to the console